# Como modificar un archivo de txt desde el programa de phyton

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quería saber como modificar un archivo de texto desde el programa ( no es agregar una línea, sino modificar un dato ya ingresado)
Por ejemplo, tengo txt de la siguiente forma:

```
Numero,fecha,articulo
1,01/2019,remera
2,02/2020,pantalon
3,03/2021,buzo
```

entonces, digamos que lei el archivo con el readlines() y todo eso, y decidí ordenarlo en un diccionario con numero como clave

```
dic = {"1":["01/2019","remera"],"2":["02/2020","pantalon"],"3":["03/2021","buzo"]}
```

se como modificar un dato dentro del diccionario (por ejemplo hacer que en la primer lista, en vez figurar remera figure "buzo), pero que tendría que hacer para que el cambio también se vea en el archivo txt original?

Muchas gracias

```
#Informacion_txt sería lo que me devuelve el leer el archivo y hacer un diccionario

dic = {"1":["01/2019","remera"],"2":["02/2020","pantalon"],"3":["03/2021","buzo"]}

dato_a_mod = input("Ingrese una opción: ")
lista_opciones = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]
while dato_a_mod not in lista_opciones:
  dato_a_mod = input("Ingrese una opción válida: ")
for opcion in lista_opciones:
 if dato_a_mod == opcion:
   nuevo_dato = input("Ingrese la modificación: ")
   dic[operacion][int(dato_a_mod) - 1]  = nuevo_dato
```

Comment: Tienes que grabar todo el archivo tras modificar el diccionario.

Comment: Hola Julia, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Como dijo Candid Moe, el mejor truco es reescribir todo el archivo una vez hayas hecho los cambios necesarios. Es decir, convertir tu diccionario nuevamente en un archivo de texto. Lo que podés hacer es una función que haga justamente eso y ejecutarla, por ejemplo, cuando el usuario sale del programa.

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos! Ahora intento hacer eso.